# Sound increasing and decreasing randomly in XMoto

Tags: 11.04, games, sound

I have installed the wonderful XMoto game in my Ubuntu 11.04 (2.6.38-8-generic) and when I start the game my sound control became crazy. The sounds decreases and increases randomly. If I close the game this strange behavior still continues.

Well, I think this isn't a problem with Ubuntu, Gnome, KDE at all because in my older installations (Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10) the same thing happen. But I don't know how to solve it.

My Audio device is (lspci | grep Audio):

> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)

My sounds is ok for other things, I can hear several things at the same time, etc.

So, anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21782/sound-increasing-and-decreasing-randomly-in-xmoto-for-ubuntu-11-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved the problem.
Looks like the problem was with my led button to increase the sound, over the keybord.
Ubuntu detects it as a input device.
Xmoto try to detect the input devices to able joysticks so this fake joystick make the sound crazy.

Running

> sudo ln -s /dev/input/js0 /dev/js1

and

sudo ln -s /dev/input/js1 /dev/js0

solves the problem to me.

js0 device is my led button.
js1 device is my joystick.